# Problems creating more schemas in PostgreSQL + .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-core

We recently created a web project in .NET Core and are using PostgreSQL via NPGSQL Entity Framework extension. At first, there were no problems at all. But when trying to add more schemas, the new schema was not created. According to other posts on the Internet, we should not be limited to any number of schemas. Does anybody know what might cause the problem?

P.S.: After dropping the original schema, the new schema was successfully created. However, trying to add next schema without dropping the previous one seems like a problem.

FooDbContext.cs

```
public class FooDbContext : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// For unit testing.
    /// </summary>
    public FooDbContext()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public FooDbContext(DbContextOptions<FooDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PersonOnProject> PeopleOnProjects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("TestingFoo");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<Model.FooDbContext>((provider, builder) => {
                builder.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalDb"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("TestingFoo"));
            });
            services.AddMvc();
        }

....

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.ApplicationServices.GetService<Model.FooDbContext>().Database.EnsureCreated();
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404
                && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Maybe provide bit code so people can see how you're trying to create them

Comment: I got no exceptions, when the model creation code was executed. Only when trying to insert new entity. I have added the code samples...

Comment: Did you tried using lowercase schema?

Comment: Are you using database migrations? If yes, check the migrations file created, you will find an "up" and "down" method. Up method contains code to create tables and "down" to drop tables.

Comment: We did not find a .NET Core EF package for Postgre that would be able to support migrations, so far...

Comment: @Tseng we have just tried creating additional schema with lower case name, but the result was the same - the schema has not been created.

Answer (score 0):

We found we had difficulty "seeing" other schemas besides "public" until we adjusted the connection string to connect to the cluster instead of the instance.